# Schengen visa for unregistered freelancers from India

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I’m a freelance/contract developer who works with a Netherland company. I’m not sure which visa I need to apply for business or tourist?

I don’t have my business registered but I have been working with the company since more than a year now. I’m now planning a trip to Netherlands and everything is ready like invitation letter from the company, tickets, accommodation and everything is paid by the company. But I’m not sure if I should go with Business Schengen visa or the tourist one?

I don’t have my business registered since it is not required as per the income/revenue. The invitation letter specifically mentions that this is for business purpose and meet with the company.

Comment: You don't need a business to get a business visa.  A business visa just means the main reason for your travel is for business (work) purposes, and not tourism.

Comment: You don't need a registered business to apply for a Schdngen visa. You have to apply for a bhsiness visa as that is your purpose of visit. It is mandatory to register for GST if you export services from India, regardless of turnover. Though this may not impact your visa, but I thought of informing you as you talked about not "registering you business" because of revenue. It is not exactly business registration but GST registration and compliance is mandatory if you supply services overseas from India.